# Working with large header files

Tags: c++, compilation, header, header-files, compiler-optimization

**First a bit of background:**

I am using Visual Studio 2017 - Professional Addition

Developing a native C++ android application

I used the standard template. So I have a pure c++ (11) library where all my code is. And a precompiled header defined in the main project that links to my library.

**What I am doing**

I am working on some code that requires a large amount of embedded data.

I googled around for good ways to do this, but most seem like way to much hassle and almost always there were comments saying just to put the data directly into header files as that's the most portable way.

So I now have a number of header files that basically contain static arrays of data. **NOTE** they are not 'const' as if you do that then Visual Studio 2017 will try and display the data if you happen to move over the variable definition. So just static.

All the header files are then aggregated into one header file and this is then finally referenced in a standard cpp file. effectively making the data private to that class.

This all works fine. BUT compile times are getting to be very slow. And if I watch the output window I can see that it spends 80% of its time on the cpp file (even when there have been no changes to the data or the code)

Now this cant be the best a compiler can do. I would expect the compiler to skip this as there have been no changes that directly effect the cpp file.

I have also attempted to move things into the precompiled header. But that simply makes the pch.h file take ages to build each time.

So what am I doing wrong?

**Update**

I have double checked the files have not been changed.
If I press F6 (build) then press again, it will still rebuild the large files.

I have also tried reworking the static data so that it is defined in a cpp file. 
And this still makes no difference.

**For clarity this is an example:**

.cpp file:

```
#include "Some.h"

unsigned char _someData[] =
{
   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
   0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
};

unsigned char* Some::GetSomeData(void)
{
   return _someData;
}
```

.h file:

```
#pragma once

class Some
{
public:
static unsigned char* GetSomeData(void);
};
```

Comment: Obviously the compiler shouldn't recompile if there have been no changes in the code. That's where you should be looking. Compare the timestamps of the source and object files for instance. Secondly why put the data in a header file which is included in one cpp file. Why not just put the data in the cpp file? That is best practice.

Comment: I will double check the timestamps in a while.  The data is in a .h file as the data is generated by another offline process. This process can recreate the .h file without destroying anything else.  If I want the data to be directly in my cpp file then my toolset would need to be more complex and 'know' more about the system. That would not be a good design.

Comment: Forgot to say that I would prefer a non android only solution. Ie something I can do just in the native c++, so that it can be ported to work on apple to.

Comment: Define data in a cpp file and a getter function, and declare this getter in the .h file. BTW what framework are you using to make an application working on android and IOS?

Comment: I can confirm that none of the files are changing between builds. Just simply pressing F6 (build) twice in a row will have the same effect each time (long compile on the cpp file)

Comment: @jaudo It will take me a while to rework my tool so that it creates cpp files. but I will give that a go.   As for the framework. Its the standard native c++ cross platform template in visual studio. its called (OpenGLES Application (Android,iOS)) So far 99.9% of all my code is in the common C++ part, and that's how I would like to keep it

Comment: @jaudo so I rewored my tool. it now create a .h file that contains GetData();  and i now also have a cpp that defines the get data. And I can say that its made no difference at all.  The only change is that it now shows me many files that in total take just as long to build. I have no idea why the cpp files get built every time.

Comment: You said your cpp file was generated by a tool. Do you run your tool before every C++ build? Are you sure to run a "Build" command and not "Rebuild"?

Comment: > Now this cant be the best a compiler can do. I would expect the compiler to skip this as there have been no changes that directly effect the cpp file.
Well, MSVC isn't a stellar compiler when it comes to these things. But it really is the best it can do. You cannot expect the compiler to "skip" parts of headers because they don't affect the real code. That's just wishful thinking and very wrong.

Comment: _"I have also tried reworking the static data so that it is defined in a cpp file. And this still makes no difference."_ This surprises me. It's how I'd do it (and have done it in the past).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit You can be surprised as you like, its till true.

Comment: @jaudo  My tool is a completely separate c# project, I run it manually as a separate process. There is no way that it could be interfering with the c++ recompile.

Comment: @PaulSpain: It seems that you have misunderstood me. I am trying to say that you have almost certainly missed something, given the evidence provided. Of course you are free to ignore my advice; it's not like you came here seeking second opinions, right? :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit  your quite right.. However I already know it should not be this way. hence my question.     As it happens I do now know what the problem was.  See comments on SHR's answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In manner to save compilation time try the following:

1. Make sure you your project doesn't contains missing files. It cause re-compile even when no changes at all).
2. Don't put data in headers, place the data in c\cpp files and use the `extern` of the data variables in the headers.
3. Do not include unecessary headers from other header. (any change in header will generate recompilation of the all)
4. Always prefer to use forward declaration in headers when it is possible (instead of include).
5. Notice the difference between `#include <file>` and `#include "file"`. if you choose the wrong include method, (like use <> to include your file, or "" for system include) you spend more time in search for the file.
6. Order the include dirs from the most common to the less common, it also may save time in search for file.

If you wan't to know why a project or file is re-built or re-compiled even though there was no changes, you can do it as follows:

1. Menu: tools -> options
2. In the opened Options left pan: Project and solution-> Build and Run:
3. Then in the right pan: change MSBuild project build output verbosity to Diagnostic.
4. Build the project
5. Find in the diagnostic data  why it been re-compiled.

Good luck

Comment: Your first number 3 is the important one. Of course, the cause of the recurrent recompilation is the next thing, but fixing that won't solve the long compile times an sich.

Comment: Ok so thank for the tip! I have finally got it.  By using the Diagnostic setting, its all clear.   The code was being rebuilt because of a missing file. So even when there are no changes it will still rebuild everything.  Once I had this detail it was easy to find and fix the problem.  looked like I had some strange header file that was not deleted correctly but was not really needed and so did not brake the build.  Thanks very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider using data files (outside your code), that you read when you program starts. This will create some overhead (file reading time) but you will solve your compilation time problems.

Comment: I don't believe that is practical/possible when developing android applications. All the data must ship inside the APK file. There will be no way for me to load anything that was shipped.  Unless you know otherwise?

Comment: What about:
1) Not shipping data files
2) At first app start, download data files, and store them in the storage

Comment: In interesting possibility. But that sounds like a plan B sort of solution. There has to be something up with the way I am expecting the compiler to work.  But thanks for the good idea! +1

Comment: You may use resources : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources

Comment: Jaudo,  I will have to give that a close look, but it looks like that would not work in my case for native c++ / cross platform. (Forgot to say this is cross platform but that's what I mean when i said portable)